# Meaning of Full Node Logs

Tags: iri-node

This is how the most common full node log looks like:

> INFO  com.iota.iri.network.Node - toProcess = 963 , toBroadcast = 0 , toRequest = 2117 , toReply = 32 / totalTransactions = 3313092

What do the terms "toProcess", "toBroadcast", "toRequest", "toReply", "totalTransactions" stand for?

Answer (score 8):

The key part of the IRI codebase here is [`Node.java`](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/567a39aa6077456bc60a4c3ba335c310e88428ac/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java).

**toProcess** corresponds to the length of the `receiveQueue` of the node. Transactions are added to this queue after they have been received from a neighbour and validated to be valid transactions. The receive queue stores a list of pairs of Transaction Data and Neighbour fields. Transactions in the queue are processed by being popped off it and stored in the node's database, and broadcasted to other neighbours if they are new transactions.

**toBroadcast** corresponds to the length of the `broadcastQueue` of the node. It is the number of transactions the node is preparing to broadcast to its neighbours, either due to the above process, or because they are transactions created at this node.

**toRequest** corresponds to `transactionRequester.numberOfTransactionsToRequest()`. The node works out how large this is by working backwards from the current milestone, and seeing how many new transactions it needs to download.

**toReply** corresponds to the length of the `replyQueue` of the node. This is a list of pairs of Transaction hashes and Neighbour fields, and is designed to prepare transactions to send to neighbours that requested them.

**totalTransactions** corresponds to `TransactionViewModel.getNumberOfStoredTransactions(tangle)`, clearly the total number of transactions stored in the node's database.

Comment: any idea why totalTransactions go down at times?

Comment: @slippedon See this question: https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/594/why-does-total-transactions-in-log-fluctuate